# Jupyter Notebookをpdfに書き出すと、マークダウンの表の中のセル内改行が反映されない

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pdf, latex, markdown

初めまして。
初心者です。よろしくお願いします。
Jupyter Notebookで書いた文書をpdfに書き出したいと思い、以下のHPを参照して、TeX LiveとInkscapeをインストールし、メニューからFile > Download as > PDF via LaTex (.pdf)と選択して、日本語でpdfに書き出すことはどうにか成功しました。

https://mana.bi/wiki.cgi?page=Jupyter+Lab%A4%AB%A4%E9%C6%FC%CB%DC%B8%ECPDF%A4%F2%BD%D0%CE%CF%A4%B9%A4%EB2021#p4

このノートの中で、マークダウンで以下のような構造の表を書きました（実際の内容は異なります）。

```
| 野菜の名前 | 旬の季節 | おいしい食べ方 |
| :--- | :--- | :---| 
| キャベツ | 春から秋 | お好み焼き、焼きそば、ロールキャベツ、茹でキャベツ、 キャベツ炒め、無限キャベツ、回鍋肉、ちゃんぽん| 
| 大根 | 冬から春 | ふろふき大根、お鍋、肉大根、大根ステーキ、刺身のつま、大根おろし、雪見鍋、大根ステーキ、おでん | 
| トマト | 春から秋 | トマトサラダ、トマトソーススパゲティ、ラタトゥイユ、トマト鍋、トマトと卵炒め、ピザ、カプレーゼ |
```

3列目の”おいしい食べ方”の欄に割と長い文を書いたところ、pdfに書き出すと、表の右端が文書の外側にはみ出してしまいました。

[image: pdfに出力した表]

そこで、"おいしい食べ方"列の文中に`<br>`コードを入れて以下のようにセル内改行してみました。

```
| 野菜の名前 | 旬の季節 | おいしい食べ方 |
| :--- | :--- | :---| 
| キャベツ | 春から秋 | お好み焼き、焼きそば、ロールキャベツ、<br>茹でキャベツ、 キャベツ炒め、無限キャベツ、回鍋肉、ちゃんぽん| 
| 大根 | 冬から春 | ふろふき大根、お鍋、肉大根、大根ステーキ、<br>刺身のつま、大根おろし、雪見鍋、大根ステーキ、おでん | 
| トマト | 春から秋 | トマトサラダ、トマトソーススパゲティ、<br>ラタトゥイユ、トマト鍋、トマトと卵炒め、ピザ、カプレーゼ |
```

すると、以下のように、ノートブック上ではきちんと表示されました。

| 野菜の名前 | 旬の季節 | おいしい食べ方 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| キャベツ | 春から秋 | お好み焼き、焼きそば、ロールキャベツ、 茹でキャベツ、 キャベツ炒め、無限キャベツ、回鍋肉、ちゃんぽん |
| 大根 | 冬から春 | ふろふき大根、お鍋、肉大根、大根ステーキ、 刺身のつま、大根おろし、雪見鍋、大根ステーキ、おでん |
| トマト | 春から秋 | トマトサラダ、トマトソーススパゲティ、 ラタトゥイユ、トマト鍋、トマトと卵炒め、ピザ、カプレーゼ |

ところが、pdfに書き出すと、`<br>`が無視されてしまうようで、やはり一行で表示され、表の右端がはみ出してしまいます。

pdfに書き出した時に表がはみ出ないようにするには、またはセル内改行をするには、どうしたらよいのか教えていただけないでしょうか。

また、ついでなのですが、表に`<br>`を入れると、pdfに書き出す際に"505: Internal Server Error"となって失敗することがあります。なぜなのかご存じでしたら教えてください。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: もしかしたら使っている版数の問題かもしれませんね。こんな記事があるようです。[nbconvert のテンプレートの書き方が変わったらしい](https://www.kenjisato.jp/post/2021/03/nbconvert-template/)

Comment: 一旦 LaTeX コードで書き出して、longtable のパラメータを `p{30em}` などに変更してから eLaTeX でコンパイルすると希望通りになりますが、面倒くさいですよね。。。

Comment: ＠kunif　コメントありがとうございます。nbconvertというのはよく仕様が変わるのですね。Jupyter NotebookもTeX LiveもInkscapeも最近一週間以内にダウンロードしたばかりで、最新のものだと思うのですが。どの版ならOKなのかまで追求するエネルギーがありません・・・。

Comment: @metropolis 一応回避策はあるのですね。ありがとうございます。にっちもさっちも行かなくなったら試してみたいと思います。

Comment: まあ新たに見つかったor対応し切れていない問題かもしれないので、開発元のIssuesを検索したり、無ければ新しいIssueを立ててみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: @kunif ご助言ありがとうございます。”開発元のIssues”へというと、このような感じでですか？[nbconvert into PDF fails to process exclamation mark in Latex #6189](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/6189)

Comment: はい、そうだと思われます。

Comment: `| キャベツ | 春から秋 | Pandocは、あるマークアップ形式から他の形式へ変換する Haskell ライブラリと、そのライブラリを用いたコマンドラインツールです。`
… という行を入れるとやたら改行してます (環境: colab)
(禁則処理, 英単語の存在などに関係あるのかも？)
(この行が他の行に比べ短いと, 改行されなさそう)

Comment: もしも "Jupyter Notebook" が広義の意味([Project Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/), Notebook, ...)ではなく, 狭義の `jupyter notebook` を指しているのなら, `JupyterLab`で試してはどうでしょう？ (もしかするとエラーはそのせいかも？)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markdown code を PDF に変換する場合、実際には `jupyter-nbconvert` や `pandoc` で `Markdown code -> LaTeX code -> PDF` へと変換されています。

問題と見做されている件のテーブルですが、`LaTeX` コードでは以下の様に変換されています。

```latex
\begin{longtable}[]{@{}lll@{}}
\toprule
野菜の名前 & 旬の季節 & おいしい食べ方\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
キャベツ & 春から秋 &
お好み焼き、焼きそば、ロールキャベツ、茹でキャベツ、
キャベツ炒め、無限キャベツ、回鍋肉、ちゃんぽん\tabularnewline
大根 & 冬から春 &
ふろふき大根、お鍋、肉大根、大根ステーキ、刺身のつま、大根おろし、雪見鍋、大根ステーキ、おでん\tabularnewline
トマト & 春から秋 &
トマトサラダ、トマトソーススパゲティ、ラタトゥイユ、トマト鍋、トマトと卵炒め、ピザ、カプレーゼ\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

`tabular` 環境の column alignment は `lll` となっていて、これは 1, 2, 3列目の配置を左寄せ(left-justified)するという意味になります。コメントにも書きましたが、`LaTeX` では以下の様な「仕様」になっています。

[LaTeX/Tables: Text wrapping in tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Text_wrapping_in_tables)

> LaTeX's algorithms for formatting tables have a few shortcomings. One is that **it will not automatically wrap text in cells, even if it overruns the width of the page**. For columns that will contain text whose length exceeds the column's desired width, it is recommended that **you use the `p` attribute and specify the desired width of the column** (although it may take some trial-and-error to get the result you want).

つまり、これはバグではなく、PDF へ変換する手段として `LaTeX` を利用した故の必然的な結果と言えます。

以降、対処の一例を述べます(**あくまでも一例です**)。

#### `LuaLaTeX` を利用して `LaTeX` コードを PDF に変換

デフォルトでは `XeLaTeX` で変換が行われますが、今回は `LuaLaTeX` を使います。これは `LuaLaTeX` の機能(`Lua` code の実行)を利用するためです。`jupyter_notebook_config.py` に以下の設定を追加します。

###### jupyter_notebook_config.py

```py
c.PDFExporter.latex_command = [u"lualatex", u"{filename}", "-quiet"]
```

※ 手元の環境の Ubuntu Linux では `jupyter_notebook_config.py` は `$HOME/.jupyter/` にあります。もしくは `jupyter notebook --generate-config` を実行して新規に作成します。

#### [tabulary](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabulary) を利用してテーブルをレンダリング

[longtable](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) とは異なって、`tabulary.sty` ではカラムの幅を適当に計算してくれます。例えば左寄せで折り返しを行う場合には `L` を指定します(右寄せ `r -> R`, センタリング `c -> C` をそれぞれ指定)。

##### `longtable` の場合

```latex
\begin{longtable}[]{@{}lllp{30em}@{}}
```

##### `tabulary` の場合

```latex
\begin{tabulary}[]{@{}llL@{}}
```

#### `nbconvert` のテンプレートファイルに変換用のコードを追加

質問文中の記事 [Jupyter Labから日本語PDFを出力する2021](https://mana.bi/wiki.cgi?page=Jupyter+Lab%A4%AB%A4%E9%C6%FC%CB%DC%B8%ECPDF%A4%F2%BD%D0%CE%CF%A4%B9%A4%EB2021#p4) の「nbconvertテンプレートの改変」で言及されている `index.tex.j2` に以下のコードを追加します。

```latex
%===============================================================================
% Latex Article
%===============================================================================

((*- block docclass -*))
\documentclass[a4paper,lualatex,ja=standard]{bxjsarticle}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{luacode}

\renewenvironment{longtable}[2][]{
 \tabulary{\textwidth}{#2}
}{\endtabulary}
\renewcommand{\endhead}{}

\begin{luacode}
  luatexbase.add_to_callback('process_input_buffer',
    function (buf)
      return buf:gsub(
        '^%s*(\\begin%{longtable%}%[.*%].*@%{%})(.*)(.)(@%{%}.*)$',
        function (a, b, c, d)
          return a..b..c:upper()..d
        end)
    end, 'wrap text at last column in table')
\end{luacode}

((*- endblock docclass -*))
```

特に説明はしませんが、`longtable` 環境を `tabulary` 環境に置き換えて、テーブルの最後のカラムで自動折り返しを行う様に変更する処理を行っています。

```latex
\begin{longtable}[]{@{}lll@{}}

=>

\begin{tabulary}[]{@{}llL@{}}
```

上記の変更を行って、`Download as > PDF via LaTex (.pdf)` を選択した結果が以下になります。

[image: PDF]

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。LuaLatexに変えて必要な設定をすれば自動折り返しできるのですね！必要なコードを書いてくださったのですね。感謝申し上げます。
ご指示のように実際に設定をしてみたのですが、'Download as > PDF via LaTex (.pdf)'を選んだ後、Internal Server Errorになってしまいました。エラーコードは次のコメントに載せます。エラーの原因にお心当たりがありましたら教えていただけますでしょうか？

Comment: The error was:

nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
Failed to run "xelatex notebook.tex -quiet" command:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./notebook.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bxjscls/bxjsarticle.cls
Document Class: bxjsarticle 2021/02/02 v2.5 BXJS document classes
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)

Comment: (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bxjscls/bxjscompat.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))

! Class bxjsarticle Error: Option 'lualatex' used on wrong engine.

See the bxjsarticle class documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

Comment: l.696 ...js@engine@opt' used on wrong engine}\@ehc
                                                  
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.696 ...js@engine@opt' used on wrong engine}\@ehc
                                                  
No pages of output.
Transcript written on notebook.log.

Comment: エラーメッセージをみますと、`xelatex` のままになっています。Windows の場合 `jupyter_notebook_config.py` のパスはどこなのでしょう…？(こちらの環境は Ubuntu Linux なので、よく判りません)

Comment: ”Windows の場合 jupyter_notebook_config.py のパスはどこなのでしょう…？”のご質問についてですが、
パスは、C:\Users\(ユーザ名)\.jupyterです。

Comment: そうなりますと、jupyter_notebook_config.py が読み込まれていない事になりますね。

Comment: コマンド’ラインで’jupyter notebook --debug’してみたところ、jupyter_notebook_config.pyのパス名の区切り文字が'\'だったため、Syntax Errorになって読み込まれていなかったらしいことが分かりました。

Comment: ご指示のように設定したjupyter_notebook_config.pyが読み込まれるようになったようなので、再度Jupyter Notebookを立ち上げて表を含むnotebookをPDF化してみたところ、できました！！！きれいに表の中身が折り返されていました。素人には思いつかない高度な技でドンピシャな解決策をご提案下さり、本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

texlive-xetex の XeLatex (もしくは LuaLaTeX)で PDFを作成する場合, 内部で Pandasを使用してるようだけど, pipe_tables だと自動改行になにか問題がありそうです。

grid_tables での作表なら大丈夫そう。ただし …

- fixed-width font のはず
- Jupyterではプレビューできない

```
| 野菜の名前 | 旬の季節 | おいしい食べ方 |
| :--- | :--- | :---| 
| キャベツ | 春から秋 | Pandocは、あるマークアップ形式から他の形式へ変換する Haskell ライブラリと、そのライブラリを用いたコマンドラインツールです。
| キャベツ | 春から秋 | お好み焼き、焼きそば、ロールキャベツ、茹でキャベツ、 キャベツ炒め、無限キャベツ、回鍋肉、ちゃんぽん| 
| 大根 | 冬から春 | ふろふき大根、お鍋、肉大根、大根ステーキ、刺身のつま、大根おろし、雪見鍋、大根ステーキ、おでん | 
| トマト | 春から秋 | トマトサラダ、トマトソーススパゲティ、ラタトゥイユ、トマト鍋、トマトと卵炒め、ピザ、カプレーゼ |

---

+---------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 野菜の名前    | 旬の季節      | おいしい食べ方                                                                                     |
+===============+===============+====================================================================================================+
| キャベツ      | 春から秋      | お好み焼き、焼きそば、ロールキャベツ、茹でキャベツ、 キャベツ炒め、無限キャベツ、回鍋肉、ちゃんぽん|
+---------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 大根          | 冬から春      | ふろふき大根、お鍋、肉大根、大根ステーキ、刺身のつま、大根おろし、雪見鍋、大根ステーキ、おでん     |
+---------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| トマト        | 春から秋      | トマトサラダ、トマトソーススパゲティ、ラタトゥイユ、トマト鍋、トマトと卵炒め、ピザ、カプレーゼ     |
+---------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

以下は, colabでの処理(PDF変換)結果

- 中くらいの横線より上は, 英単語と SPCを含む行を追加することで, 改行は行われるが無駄な改行が多い (あまりに長いので下の部分だけ)
- 中くらいの横線より下は, grid_tables により作表した場合の出力

[image: PDFスクショ]

---

##### 追記

[pipe_tables](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-pipe_tables)で記述しておいて通常はそのまま。
PDF生成時は加工して [grid_tables](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-grid_tables) で … も, 可能かも

```py
from IPython.display import Markdown
md = '''
ここに Markdown table 記述
'''
out = !echo "$md" |pandoc --from markdown --to markdown-simple_tables-pipe_tables-multiline_tables
Markdown(out.n) # ⇐ 通常は md を指定しておく
```

Comment: すみません。編集時間制限を超えてしまいましたので書き直します。ありがとうございます。サンプルとして書いてくださったgrid_tablesをJupyter NotebookにコピペしてPDFにしようとしたら、Internal Server Errorになってしまいました。試しに内容を減らして短くしてみましたが、やはり同じでした。

Comment: TexLiveではなく、colabというものでpdf化するとgrid_tablesでうまくいくかもしれないのですね。調べてみます。

Comment: 手元の環境 Jupyter-labに texlive-xetex texlive-lang-japanese など入れようとするとパンクしかねないので, 代わりに [Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb?hl=ja) +texlive-xetex texlive-lang-japanese +pandoc +inkscape … で検証している, という意味です

Comment: なるほど、そうでしたか。grid_tablesというのはjupyterでは使えない表の記述法なのではないでしょうか？

Comment: @meow909 回答に記したとおり, grid_tablesには大きな違いが 2点あります。LaTeXを使った PDF生成では Pandocが使われ, その Pandocでは 4種類のテーブルがサポートされていて(未確認だけど)どれを使っても PDF生成可能で, そのうち pipe_tablesには自動改行に問題がありそうだ, ということ。pipe_tables ↔ grid_tables 形式の変換には, 追記に記した様な方法で可能

Comment: 追記に記した変換方法では: `markdown-simple_tables-pipe_tables-multiline_tables` と指定することで, `simple_tables` と `pipe_tables` と `multiline_tables` をマイナスしてるので `grid_tables` で出力されます

Comment: 無知な質問をしてすみませんでした。"from IPython......Markdown(out.n)"のコードをコピペして実行し、PDFにしてみましたが、表の内容が長いとinternal server errorになります。短いとPDFになりますが、きれいな表にならずに、コードの状態の文字列がそのまま出力されました。いろいろご提案、ありがとうございました。

Comment: @meow909 `JupyterLab`は試しましたか？ 頻繁に internal server error出るようなら再インストール考慮した方がよいのでは？
また, 追記で記したのは"容易に切り替えることができる方法" であって, 普通に Markdown Cell に結果をコピペしても構いません  … いろいろ試してみては？

Comment: JupyterLab試しました。同じ問題が起こりました。Internal Server Errorが起こるのは、やはり表のセルの中身が長い時に限定されているようなので、再インストールで治るとも思えないのですが・・・。最後の手段としてはとっておこうと思います。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @meow909 `conda`で `nbconvert`だけでも更新かけてみては？

Comment: 他の回答者様からのご指摘で、jupyter_notebook_config.pyがちゃんと読み込まれていなかったらしいことが分かりました。パス名の区切り文字が'\'だったため、Syntax Errorになってしまっていたようです。'/'に書き換えてからは、Internal Server Errorにならなくなったようです。ご助言ありがとうございました。